# Duplicate classes problem when trying to build app

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build my app, I get errors telling that somes classes are duplicated. They say they appear in both org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 and org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21.

I use two external libraries : androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.0 and androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1. Build uses Gradle version 8.1.1, Gradle plugin version 8.0.2, build tool version 33.0.2, target Android 33. My app is written in Java.

I have tried to follow the link [Fix dependency resolution errors](https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies#resolution_errors) but couldn't get any help from it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.0 to androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.7 solved the problem!

Comment: Took some time to find wich of the updated dependencies introduced those 100 kotlin errors into my java only project. But this is the one. Thank you.